# I want given array of unique data given those example

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array
like 
var data= [1,1,3,4,2,4,5,6,7,5,4]
and I need the unique array of data without a loop or any Lodash and underscore js function

Comment: `console.log([...new Set(data)]);`....? http://jsfiddle.net/1wk9mxbq/ May you please show your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for ES6/ES2015: Using the Set, the single line solution is:

```
var data= [1,1,3,4,2,4,5,6,7,5,4] ;
var uniqueItems = Array.from(new Set(data);
```

Or shortened using spread operator

```
var uniqueItems = [...new Set(data)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Set

```js
 var data= [1,1,3,4,2,4,5,6,7,5,4] ;
 const unique = [...new Set(data)];
 console.log(unique);
```

Comment: If you want ES5, you can use 
    `data.filter((value, index, array) => array.indexOf(value) === index);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [uniq()](https://underscorejs.org/#uniq) of [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/) as below. This also have `sort` option.

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';

var data= [1,1,3,4,2,4,5,6,7,5,4];
var unique = _.uniq(data);
```